# callback to parse function in scrapy class

Tags: python, scrapy, discord, discord.py, screen-scraping

I've been trying to make a Discord 'bot' of sorts with an integrated Scrapy spider that scrapes data from a website (that has no APIs) and outputs the parsed data depending on the command sent on Discord to the bot.

I've managed to nail down the scraping part as I can get the data I need from a list array and output it in a filesystem file with Scrapy's commands:

```py
import scrapy

class locg(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'spiderbot'
    start_urls = ['https://leagueofcomicgeeks.com/comics/new-comics']

    def start_requests(self):
        headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0'}
        for url in self.start_urls:
                yield scrapy.Request(url, headers=headers)

    def parse(self, response):
        for items in response.xpath('.//ul[@class="comic-list-thumbs item-list-thumbs item-list"]'):

            publishers = items.xpath('.//div[@class="publisher color-offset"]/text()').extract()
            issues = items.xpath(".//div[@class='title color-primary']//a/text()").extract()

            i = 0
            for publisher in publishers:
                if "Marvel Comics" in publisher:
                    print(issues[i])
                i = i+1
```

With this code I can match in the list every issue name that is with publisher Marvel Comics.

I changed the code to integrate it with the Discord python API, the problem is I can't call the `parse` function from the Scrapy class outside of it so that I can make sure it runs whenever a function inside the Discord class gets called by the discord command.

So this is what I currently have:

```py
import discord
import os
import scrapy

marvel = []
dc = []

class locg(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'spiderbot'
    start_urls = ['https://leagueofcomicgeeks.com/comics/new-comics']

    def start_requests(self):
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0'}
        for url in self.start_urls:
                yield scrapy.Request(url, headers=headers)

    def parse(self, response):
        for items in response.xpath('.//ul[@class="comic-list-thumbs item-list-thumbs item-list"]'): 

            publishers = items.xpath('.//div[@class="publisher color-offset"]/text()').extract()
            issues = items.xpath(".//div[@class='title color-primary']//a/text()").extract()

            i = 0
            for publisher in publishers:
                if "Marvel Comics" in publisher:
                    marvel.append(issues[i])
                if "DC Comics" in publisher:
                    dc.append(issues[i])
                i = i+1


client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    test = locg()
    test.parse()

    if message.content.startswith('-marvel'):
        await message.channel.send(marvel)

    if message.content.startswith('-dc'):
        await message.channel.send(dc)

client.run('token')
```

When I run this and I call the command on my Discord server the bots just gives me `[]` so the empty list from the global variable I defined at the start of the code. Which makes me think the Scrapy class isn't running when I call the command and so the variable is empty.

I tried to instanciate the class with

```py
    test = locg()
    test.parse()
```

But I get `No value for argument 'response' in method call` and I'm not really sure how to define the response value in here.

Does anyone have any pointers into this?
I realize that maybe this isn't really what Scrapy was designed to do so please do tell me if so, I'll look for other ways to do this.

I appreciate any and all help, please let me know if I should give more info or if I should've done anything different with my first question. This is my first day on the website.

Thank you.